# Ansible loops over lists and array mixin

Tags: ansible

I'm currently trying to work on a task which will create directories for two differents services but I've trouble solving how am I suppose to do that using ansible loops.

Here is the object:

```
obj:
  metadata:
    uuid:
    version:

  services:
    - server:
      archive: binary.tar.gz
      dirs:
        bindir: /path/to/bindir/
        confdir: /path/to/confdir/
        tmpdir: /path/to/tmpdir/

    - client:
      archive: binary.tar.gz
      dirs:
        tmpdir: /path/to/tmpdir
```

And here is my associated task:

```
#Creating directories
- name: Creating directories for server and client mode.
  file:
    path: "{{ item.1.dirs['tmpdir'] }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ item.0.metadata.uuid }}"
    group: "{{ item.0.metadata.uuid }}"
    mode: 0750
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ obj }}"
    - services
```

Now, I'm a little bit disturbed by how loops works on ansible and a little bit stick for now with my current iteration, so, could you help me to find a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Did you check [this documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html)?

Comment: Of course I did it :D But I can't found my exemple.

Comment: Try `with_items: "{{ object.services }}"`.

Comment: Also, don't try to be too clever. Readability matters. If all you have is server and client, and not more, just write the same code twice, once for server and one for client.

Comment: I can't do that as I need both the metadata dict and the services list and subelements, that why I used subelements in the first place. However, for your information, I've already try to use the with_items loop and it works but so I can't use the upper values.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides, the issue here is that I've other tasks that rely on the services list plus the metadata dict to be able to grab and exctract the archive from a builded url onto the builded directories.

Comment: I think that, for a start, you should rename the `obj`. `obj` means really nothing. What is that thing? Whenever you have to name something in a meaningless way it is a hint that your code needs to be reorganized.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides that's not the actual name of my object, it's just a redacted name here ;-) - My issue is with the subelements loop, regular loops using with_items are perfectly working. Now, I'm trying to use subelements as I'm required to call values from two differents part of my object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48478/discussion-between-dr-i-and-antonis-christofides).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments you want to create directories for `obj.services.#.dirs.tmpdir` items with details from `obj.metadata`. The solution with `width_items: "{{ object.services }}"` is nearly working - but you don't have access to `obj.metadata`. The thing is - there is only one `obj.metadata` at all and so you don't need to refer to it in the loop. You can use it directly.

```
- name: Creating directories for server and client mode.
  file:
    path: "{{ item.dirs['tmpdir'] }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ obj.metadata.uuid }}"
    group: "{{ obj.metadata.uuid }}"
    mode: 0750
  with_items:
    - "{{ obj.services }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer, even if it's not needed anymore, it will help people, additionally, we can now a day use the way more improved loop and associated keywords such as documented in here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html